# Find out second point of a line in 3D

Tags: math

Hy guys,

I have point1 which is (X0,Y0,Z0). The line starts from this point at an angle theta with a length of L.

How can I find out point2?

Comment: Can you be more specific how point2 relates to point1?

Comment: Are you sure this is not 2D? How can a line have length? Are you talking about segment? Between what directions is your angle measured?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry / [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need two angles (thetha and phi) to set direction in 3D.
Let's assume that you have these two angles.

Lets suggest that we operate in orthonormal basis XYZO' (where O' is (X0,Y0,Z0)), thus rotation is (thetha, phi) = (0, 0). Rotated(counterclockwise) basis is X'Y'Z'O', where vector coordinates is (0, 0, L). You need to calculate coordinates of vector in old basis XYZO', thereby you need to find [transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix). In this case of transformation only rotation is present, so we can construct transformation matrix from [basic rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations). R = Rz(theta)*Ry(phi). So second point in XYZO' is R * (0,0,L). in XYZO is R*(0,0,L) + O', or (Lcos(theta)sin(phi), Lsin(theta)sin(phi), Lcos(phi)) + O'